# How to use mysql stored procedure parameter in JSON_EXTRACT

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7

how can i use mysql stored procedure parameter in JSON_EXTRACT.

Table:

```
SELECT * FROM table1;
col1: {"a1":{"a11":"101","a12":"102"},"a2":{"a22":"201","a23":"202"}}
```

Store procedure code:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS my_procedure;
DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE `my_procedure` (IN attr varchar(50))
BEGIN
  SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(col1, '$.',attr,'.a11') FROM table1;
END//
DELIMITER ;
```

Call stored procedure:

```
call my_procedure('a1');
```

Error:

```
ERROR 3143 (42000): Invalid JSON path expression. The error is around character position 2.
```

If i change the stored procedure code to:

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(col1, '$.a1.a11') FROM table1; /* this will work*/
```

but want to pass the JSON_EXTRACT path in the stored procedure parameter. I am using mysql 5.7.21
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should CONCAT() your `attr` parameter with the rest of the path to make it valid path expression.

e.g.

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(col1, CONCAT("$." , attr, ".a11"));
```

Demo:

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/pLrpXBpyZCEX6FySvWqiXz/0